# Are "to splint his broken legs" and "to set his broken legs" the same and can they be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

The dictionary has the noun "**splint**" but doesn't have the verb "**to splint**". However some technical medical sites say "**he splinted his broken legs**".

> [splint](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/splint?q=splint) noun  /splɪnt/
>
> ​a long piece of wood or metal that is tied to a broken arm or leg to
> keep it still and in the right position

---

And the dictionary also has

> ​[set](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/set_1?q=set) [transitive, intransitive] **set (something)** to put a broken bone
> into a fixed position and hold it there, so that it will join together
> again and get better; to get better in this way
>
> The surgeon set her broken arm.

Are "**to splint his broken legs**" and "**to set his broken legs**" the same and can they be used interchangeably?

Or **do we have different words that people often use in everyday conversations?**

Comment: 'Splint' and 'set' are not interchangeable. Splinting is just one way of immobilising a broken limb to set it; other methods are possible including total enclosure in a plaster cast.

Comment: Reducing a fracture is often called resetting it.

Comment: In providing dictionary definitions, it should be clear that there is a difference in meaning. Just because you *set* a bone does not mean you use a *splint* in order to do so.

Comment: And a splint is not a wooden stick like it was years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English tends to evolve more quickly than some other languages. In particular, there is a tendency for words that were once only used as nouns to become verbs. This will happen particularly often in technical contexts (for example, medicine), where the existing language lacks a detail that is useful, or where creating a new verbs 'saves time' by eliminating a longer sentence.

So 'to splint' may not be in most dictionaries, but possibly would be found in a medical dictionary.

"To splint" and "to set" are similar, but not identical in meaning. "To set a leg" would mean "to correct a fracture by some undefined method", which could be with a splint, or a plaster cast, or some other treatment. "To splint", even for somebody with no knowledge of medicine, very obviously must mean "to correct a fracture with a splint".

Pedantic people sometime resist this process by which words can change from nouns into verbs by simply adding 'to', but it happens all the time, and is very useful.

Two more examples I can think of:

> "To plate" - to place food onto a plate ahead of serving it to a diner.

> "To table" - to place something (eg a plate of food, or a legal document) on a table, and hence it has acquired an abstract sense of bringing something like a legal motion forward for discussion or a vote.

The first example is relatively new - something I heard first in cooking shows in the last decade or so, and which I have to admit I illogically don't like. The second example is very old (especially in the legal sense of 'tabling a motion').

There's [a good example here](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-verbing-1691035) of both why "verbing nouns" happens, and how some people resist it as "bad English". ("To verb" is in fact itself a neologism you won't find in dictionaries yet, invented as a deliberate joke about the process of turning nouns into verbs.)

Oddly enough, "nouning verbs" is utterly routine, and accompanied by well-known set of grammatical rules and suffixes (eg accept-ance, act-ion, auction-eer, move-ment, happen-stance, play-er,), plus the whole 'gerund' noun/verb thing, which is a whole other can of worms.

One of the strengths of the English language is how words can be repurposed* in this way, and it is usually completely obvious to a listener what the new word means, even if they have never heard it before.

*"to repurpose", from the noun "purpose", converted to a verb along with the addition of a prefix to mean "to use for a new purpose".